# UITableViewCell - image is disaapearring whent tableview is scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

in this code when my `UITableView` is load 'lineImage, shows image at the end of cell well , but when i am scrolling tableview some images of line are disappearring and some are remaining. any help?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UILabel *preferenceLabel;
    UILabel *line1Label;
    UILabel *line2Label;
    UIImageView *lineImage;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        lineImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 70.0, 320.0, 2.0)];
        lineImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        lineImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator bar.png"];
        lineImage.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineImage];
        [lineImage release];

        preferenceLabel = [appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 234.0, 20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blackColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                                           fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        preferenceLabel.tag = 2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:preferenceLabel];
        [preferenceLabel release];

        line1Label=[appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,20.0,234.0,20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blueColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor] fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        line1Label.tag = 3;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:line1Label];
        [line1Label release];

        line2Label=[appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,35.0,234.0,20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blueColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor] fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        line2Label.tag = 4;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:line2Label];
        [line2Label release];   

    } 
    else {
            lineImage = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            preferenceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            line1Label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            line2Label = (UILabel  *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    }


    // Configure the cell...

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 


    preferenceLabel.text = @"Preference Label ";
    line1Label.text=@"Line1 Label";
    line2Label.text=@"Line2 Label";

    return cell;


}
```

Comment: raval: try remove this block `if (cell == nil)` and let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [UIImage imageNamed:] you don't have to release it since you don't alloc yourself...

Comment: he doesn't do this. Just a confusing variable naming scheme

Comment: He's not releasing lineImage.image (that I see); he is releasing lineImage; but that's a UIImageView that he allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your lineImage lies completely within the bounds of your cells? (your rowHeight is >= 72.0) If not it may be the case that your cells are overlapping some of your content and obscuring lineImage.

Answer (score 0):

place

```
 lineImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator bar.png"];
```

code after

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of adding imageview for separator, I am happy by using this.

```
mailSubscritionTable.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UILabel *preferenceLabel;
    UILabel *line1Label;
    UILabel *line2Label;
    UIImageView *lineImage;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        lineImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 70.0, 320.0, 2.0)];
        lineImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
//removed a line of code and added at the end
        lineImage.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineImage];
        [lineImage release];

        preferenceLabel = [appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 234.0, 20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blackColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                                           fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        preferenceLabel.tag = 2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:preferenceLabel];
        [preferenceLabel release];

        line1Label=[appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,20.0,234.0,20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blueColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor] fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        line1Label.tag = 3;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:line1Label];
        [line1Label release];

        line2Label=[appDelegate newLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,35.0,234.0,20.0) PrimaryColor:[UIColor blueColor] selectedColor:[UIColor blackColor] fontSize:14.0 fontName:@"Verdana" bold:NO noOfLines:1];
        line2Label.tag = 4;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:line2Label];
        [line2Label release];   

    } 
    else {
            lineImage = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            preferenceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
            line1Label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
            line2Label = (UILabel  *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    }


    // Configure the cell...

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 

    lineImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator bar.png"];//changes
    preferenceLabel.text = @"Preference Label ";
    line1Label.text=@"Line1 Label";
    line2Label.text=@"Line2 Label";

    return cell;


}
```

please take a look at the above lines of code.i made minor changes in your code and updated.